# How do I use group by with a value that should always be included?

Tags: sql

I asked a similar question; however, I asked it incorrectly before. Let's say I have the following table:

```
+-----------+------------+-------+
| quiz_type | student_id | score |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| class     | NULL       | 10    |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| class     | NULL       | 9     |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| student   | A          | 5     |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| student   | B          | 7     |
+-----------+------------+-------+
| student   | A          | 6     |
+-----------+------------+-------+
```

I want to get the *standard deviation* of the scores for each student, but need to include the class scores for every student. In reality, the quiz_type column doesn't exist (it's just to better show the example). I need to do a `GROUP BY student_id`, but include the `NULL` values with every group. I've been struggling with this for quite a bit. Is there a good solution?

For the sake of example, I'd like to use the aggregate `AVG` function to get a table like the following:

```
+------------+---------+
| student_id | Average |
+------------+---------+
| A          | 7.5     |
+------------+---------+
| B          | 8.67    |
+------------+---------+
```

In reality I will be calling the `STDDEV_SAMP` function.

Comment: Include your db schema. You dont have a table for `quiz_type` some where else? What is your RDBMS? Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: Can a `NULL` value potentially belong to many groups?  `NULL` means unknown in SQLese, so how can you be certain of any group?

Comment: You can handle the `NULL` values by doing `GROUP BY CASE WHEN student_id IS NULL THEN 'NULL' ELSE student_id END`, but then again this might not make logical sense.

Comment: Do you mean 'null' as in 'unknown' or 'default to a value of zero'? They are two completely separate issues.

Comment: `NULL` should be included in every standard deviation calculation. For the sake of an example, I'll pretend I need to use AVG(). The result for `student A` would look like `(5+6+9+10)/4 = 7.5`

Comment: standard deviation is usually calculated for all the measures in a dataset. Doing it per student_id would be wrong. How should the expected result look like?

Comment: Sorry, I will update the question shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One clever way to do this is to self join your table in such a way that the `NULL` values get paired up with every non `NULL` entry.  Then, you can use *both* `score` columns in your calculation.  Try something like this:

```
SELECT t2.student_id,
       SUM(t2.score) / (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN student_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM students) AS nonNullScore,
       (SUM(t1.score) / COUNT(*)) * (SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN student_id IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) FROM students) AS nullScore
FROM students t1
INNER JOIN students t2
    ON t1.student_id IS NULL AND t2.student_id IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY t2.student_id
```

I tested this query in MySQL Workbench and it appears to be working.

**Output:**

```
student_id | nonNullScore | nullScore
    A      |   11.0000    |  19.0000
    B      |   7.0000     |  19.0000
```

Answer (score 1):

From the question, the mean value of score can be adjusted by adding the scores for null values to the total. The adjusted standard deviation can then be calculated from the adjusted mean per student.

```
SELECT
  student_id,
  SQRT(AVG(squared_diff)) adjusted_std_deviation
FROM (SELECT
  t.student_id,
  pow((t.score - x.adjmean), 2) squared_diff
FROM t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT avg(1.0*score) adjmean FROM t) x
WHERE student_id IS NOT NULL) y
GROUP BY student_id
ORDER BY 1
```

[Sample Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f9cdf/21)

[Calculating Standard Deviation](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/probability/descriptive-statistics/variance-std-deviation/a/calculating-standard-deviation-step-by-step)